# Firebase Cloud Function called from Android works but always gets null response

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call a Google Firebase Cloud Function that simply uses a transaction to check that something exists in my Firestore, and then delete it and one other Document. I'm calling the function from Android on a button click, and it does actually work, the entry is deleted, but the response I get back in Android is null rather than the messages I'm trying to send back.

Cloud Function:

```
//Takes in the uid of the user who sent the request and the user who received it,
// and deletes the request
exports.cancelFriendRequest = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    //Grab the parameters
    const sender = data.sender;
    const recipient = data.recipient;

    //Ensure parameters are good
    if(sender === undefined || sender === "" || recipient === undefined || recipient === "") {
        return res.status(400).send("Invalid arguments.");
    }

    const db = admin.firestore();

    //Build document references to check that friend request exists
    let receivedFriendRequestDocRef = db.doc("users/"+recipient+"/receivedFriendRequests/"+sender);
    let sentFriendRequestDocRef = db.doc("users/"+sender+"/sentFriendRequests/"+recipient);

    db.runTransaction(transaction => {
        return transaction.getAll(receivedFriendRequestDocRef, sentFriendRequestDocRef).then(docs => {
            //Check that the friend request exists
            if(!docs[0].exists) {
                return Promise.reject(new Error("Friend request does not exist."));
            }

            //Delete friend requests
            transaction.delete(receivedFriendRequestDocRef);
            transaction.delete(sentFriendRequestDocRef);

            return Promise.resolve("Friend request deleted successfully.");
        });
    }).then(result => {
        //I've also tried return res.status(200).send("Success: " + result);
        //But that wasn't working so I thought I'd try this, which I saw in a Google sample git repo
        return "Success: " + result;
    }).catch(err => {
        return err.toString();
    });
});
```

Android cloud function call:

```
public static Task<String> cancelFriendRequest(String sender, String recipient) {
        FirebaseFunctions mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();

        //Create the arguments to the callable function
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("sender", sender);
        data.put("recipient", recipient);

        return mFunctions
                .getHttpsCallable("cancelFriendRequest")
                .call(data)
                .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                        //This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                        // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                        // propagated down.
                        String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                        return result;
                    }
                });
    }
```

Function in Android that calls the cloud function:

```
private static void cancelFriendRequest(String uid) {
    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    CloudFunctions.cancelFriendRequest(userId, uid).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
            String result = task.getResult();
            Log.e("Result", "" + result);
            Snackbar.make(mRecyclerView, result, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I'm happy to provide any more information. I've also found calling the function really slow. It works very quickly if I set it to onRequest and call it by navigating to the URL manually, but onCall and calling from Android is painfully slow. Anyway, that's another issue, thanks!

EDIT: Also, the Snackbar pops up (empty, because it's returning null), a good 10-15 seconds before the documents are actually removed from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the return in your main function (on the cloud function code), so the function returns before the transaction finishes execution. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions):

> Use these recommended approaches to manage the lifecycle of your
>   functions:
>
> Resolve functions that perform asynchronous processing (also known
>   as    "background functions") by returning a JavaScript promise.

Try to return the transaction (`return db.runTransaction(transaction => {....});`) and it should work, like this:

```
//Takes in the uid of the user who sent the request and the user who received it,
// and deletes the request
exports.cancelFriendRequest = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    //Grab the parameters
    const sender = data.sender;
    const recipient = data.recipient;

    //Ensure parameters are good
    if(sender === undefined || sender === "" || recipient === undefined || recipient === "") {
        return res.status(400).send("Invalid arguments.");
    }

    const db = admin.firestore();

    //Build document references to check that friend request exists
    let receivedFriendRequestDocRef = db.doc("users/"+recipient+"/receivedFriendRequests/"+sender);
    let sentFriendRequestDocRef = db.doc("users/"+sender+"/sentFriendRequests/"+recipient);

   return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
        return transaction.getAll(receivedFriendRequestDocRef, sentFriendRequestDocRef).then(docs => {
            //Check that the friend request exists
            if(!docs[0].exists) {
                return Promise.reject(new Error("Friend request does not exist."));
            }

            //Delete friend requests
            transaction.delete(receivedFriendRequestDocRef);
            transaction.delete(sentFriendRequestDocRef);

            return Promise.resolve("Friend request deleted successfully.");
        });
    }).then(result => {
        //I've also tried return res.status(200).send("Success: " + result);
        //But that wasn't working so I thought I'd try this, which I saw in a Google sample git repo
        return "Success: " + result;
    }).catch(err => {
        return err.toString();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much!

I must have straight up forgot to put it there, because when I saw that was your response, I could swear I had already returned it, but alas I did not. Thanks again!